# Creating lines from 3D polygons in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have a task to Create simple lines from 3D polygons (pipelines created in 3D Modeling program) to operate them in ArcGIS.

What tools can be used to perform this?

Comment: Welcome, Anna Pavlenko. Please explain in more details about your task. Which 3d modelling program do you use?

Comment: Thank you. 3d model of mining pipes - from program similar to MINEDW (water flow simulation). This is not actual 3D TIN, but represent shape of pipe.i just need just simple lines - outlines around (like in first picture). When i use 3D buffer - it created buffer around each single line.  What tool can be used to resolve this task in ArcGIS?  Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS Pro application of ArcGIS Desktop or its older 3D applications (ArcScene/ArcGlobe)?  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: I am using ArcGIS 10.5, ArcPro 1.4, ArcScene.